# Should we continue use asp.net ViewState and Session in HTML5 now?

Tags: asp.net, html

If we build a business system, and we can demonstrate/ask for our client to use like as IE9+ version browsers, so, we prepared to build the system UI use html5.

As you know, html5 provides sessionStorage and localStorage, i think they can propertely instead of viewState and session, so, does it mean that we not need viewstate and session again?
Only if i need pass the client data to server, I can pass the json data from client storage to server through Ajax.

OK, could anyone tell me whether i am right or not?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use ASP.NET WebForms, you won't use ViewState.

ViewState is a concept with very bad reputation, you have to avoid it.. actually. I heard that ASP.NET WebForms 4 has a lot of improvements there, but unfortunatelly without details. But you are not able to just 'say' use localStorage instead of ViewState, since WebForms controls are dependend on it.

So, you if you wish to manage client side state with localStorage you have to create own code. And you obviously need to pick up another technology. If you are on ASP.NET stack - ASP.NET MVC is best choice.

Comment: In theory you *could* write your own custom ViewState provider, but this would be pretty crazy!

Answer (score 0):

ViewState provides you to maintain the controls state using the power of asp.net. Your dont have worry about how to accomplish this. If you choose the HTML HTML5 session state for this you will not get the state of controls in asp.net control.

In html5 you have local storage and you can have it after system restarts but it could not replace session as session are maintained on server and again accessible in asp.net code while the local storage is not accessible in asp.net code.

If you have something that is purely related to be stored on client machine then you can go for HTML5 sessions and local storage